# How to distinguish photo from text image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, ocr, statistics

I am writing OCR recognition program. It works fine with scanned texts, however, there are two problems:

1. It gives false positives on photos (some rubbish random text like "bkigopes")
2. It works quite slow

The goal is to find all images with text and extract this text. So, given mentioned problems, I need to quickly reject photos. I hope that there is some mathematical (statistical) method like calculating some median numbers, which can easily determine colorful image without any obvious structure like scanned text has.

Such method/formula should not be cheated by special kind of images, e.g. text with screenshots or magazine pages with lots of text and pictures inside. Also, colorful text (e.g. red on yellow) should not be rejected.

Has anyone experience with such problem? Any ideas or ready solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I have ***no prior knowledge/experience in this area whatsoever***, but as a complete guess:

Would an entropy calculation work?

If something has high entropy then it's likely to be an image; if low, it's likely to be something more like text.

Hope that helps a little...

Comment: Thanks for your quick idea.  I guess this may work (not sure if this will be cheated by magazine articles however). Do you have any links to implementation of such calculation?

Comment: @Alex: Nope! I'm not even too familiar with the math yet myself either (!), it's just an idea that popped into my head. :) My reasoning was that text is well-organized whereas images are rather random, so calculating the entropy might be a good idea.

Comment: lol hi Mehrdad. I don't think this will work for an OCR application since the text is stored as an image. If you've scanned documents before, you'll notice that the amount of compression (related to entropy) isn't abnormally high.

Comment: Lol, hey @tskuzzy. Hm... I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I do realize that the text is stored as an image (that was the whole point of the question...) but I would think that text is pretty much dark colors (blue/black) carefully written on top of light colors (white/gray), so I would imagine that its information content (hence entropy) is a lot lower than that of an image. Why wouldn't this be the case?

Comment: @Mehrdad: This is true for normal photos. But what about high contrast black and white photos? Also how are you calculating the entropy? Using luminance?

Comment: @tskuzzy: High-contrast *black-and-white* photos? Or do you mean grayscale? :) I haven't seen a black and white *photo* in quite a while, IIRC. And for entropy, I'm not sure what the best method is, but I think that yes, luminance and/or saturation might be good measures.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Black and white in the photography sense (i.e. grayscale), not CS sense :P. Like this http://tinyurl.com/3mklexl . But my point is that I don't think "amount of information" is enough to distinguish between pictures of text and pictures of something else. You have to look at the content of it as well.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Good point, I can see why this would break in grayscale photos with (more or less) smooth transitions. Oh well, it was just a guess anyway. :-) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks - interesting discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

**In general** this is be quite a difficult task. However given your particular application, perhaps you can make assumptions as to the input of your OCR program.

You mentioned "scanned texts". So I'm assuming this will not be applied to pictures of bulletin boards along the roads and needing to recognize text on the bulletin board in the midst of a scenic background. This implies that the range of colors is low and the contrast is high.

On the other hand, a photo typically has a very large range of colors with relatively low contrast between neighboring pixels. Of course, this assumption can easily invalidated given the many styles of photography.

So I think the first thing you could try is convert the image into black and white (not grayscale). Then look at the relative proportions of the two colors. I think a photo will be much more evenly split than a scanned document. The algorithm you use to convert the photo should be resistant to outliers so perhaps using some sort of median would be good as a threshold.

Comment: Be careful about the high-pass filtering (paragraph 3). Your assumption is that the text is only a few pixels wide -- which may or may not be true. If it's kind of bold, you'll get the *outline* of the text, not the body... so it might turn out trickier.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, tskuzzy. I think any change of pictures will have significant performance penalty on big ones. I have to figure out some mathematic approach. What do you think of looking at histogram? For text it should have two maximums. I am not sure, however, about text + pictures inside.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since magazine pages are a mix, you won't find a single technique that will take an entire image and make a determination. Some kind of segmentation will be needed. If it was me, I'd look for bands of pixels both horizontally and vertically that show low variance, and then use those to divide the image into a grid. Then you can test each cell in the grid and remove those which are photos.

Now for the photo test. Like @Mehrdad's entropy approach, you can try compression for a task like this. Different compression algorithms work differently, but a lossless Lempel-Ziv-Welch-style or equivalent compression algorithm ought to compress images of text more than photos. Measuring the size difference between uncompressed and compressed versions would estimate the entropy nicely. After all, entropy is the measure of the best possible lossless compression. With a bit of empirical work this could provide a reasonably reliable classification technique.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, morungos. I think any change of pictures will have significant performance penalty on big ones. I have to figure out some mathematic approach.